# Mac の `security` command における CMS とは何ですか?

Tags: macos

MacOS で `man security` を見ていました。このコマンドは、 CLI から keychain などを操作するためのツールらしいです。

そこに、以下の以下のサブコマンドの記述がありました。

```
     cms                         Encode or decode CMS messages.
```

この man ページをみていても、 CMS message という名詞は何回か登場するのですが、これが何を表しているのか理解ができません。

## 質問

MacOS の `security` コマンドに操作対象となっている、 CMS message とはいったい何ですか?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Encode or decode CMS messages" で Google 検索してみると以下のページがヒットするので、
CMS は **Cryptographic Message Syntax** の略らしいと分かります。

[Cryptographic Message Syntax Services | Apple Developer Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/cryptographic_message_syntax_services)

今度は "Cryptographic Message Syntax" で検索すると、Wikipedia の [暗号メッセージ構文](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E6%9A%97%E5%8F%B7%E3%83%A1%E3%83%83%E3%82%BB%E3%83%BC%E3%82%B8%E6%A7%8B%E6%96%87) がヒットし、以下の様に説明されています。

> 暗号メッセージ構文 (Cryptographic Message Syntax: CMS) は、暗号で保護されたメッセージに関するIETFの標準規格である。任意の形式のデジタルデータに対してデジタル署名、メッセージダイジェスト、メッセージ認証もしくは暗号化を行うために利用できる。